# haskell gogol - Installed Application Credentials example : Couldn't match kind ‘[Symbol]’ with ‘*’

Tags: haskell, types

I'm trying the example of [installed application credentials](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gogol-0.1.1/docs/Network-Google-Auth.html#t:Credentials)
 in [gogol package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gogol).

Here is the example(just copied from installed application credentials page):

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Data.Proxy     (Proxy (..))
import Data.Text      as T
import Data.Text.IO   as T
import System.Exit    (exitFailure)
import System.Info    (os)
import System.Process (rawSystem)
redirectPrompt :: AllowScopes (s :: [Symbol]) => OAuthClient -> proxy s -> IO (OAuthCode s)
redirectPrompt c p = do
    let url = formURL c p
    T.putStrLn $ "Opening URL " `T.append` url
    _ <- case os of
        "darwin" -> rawSystem "open"     [unpack url]
        "linux"  -> rawSystem "xdg-open" [unpack url]
    _        -> T.putStrLn "Unsupported OS" >> exitFailure
    T.putStrLn "Please input the authorisation code: "
    OAuthCode <$> T.getLine
```

While I compiled the code, I got the errors as follow:

```
Illegal kind signature: ‘s’
  Perhaps you intended to use KindSignatures
In the type signature for ‘redirectPrompt’

Illegal kind: ‘[Symbol]’ Perhaps you intended to use DataKinds
```

so I added these 2 lines in my code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures    #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds         #-}
```

Then, compiled again. It shows the following error messages:

```
• Couldn't match kind ‘[Symbol]’ with ‘*’
  When matching the kind of ‘proxy’
• In the second argument of ‘formURL’, namely ‘p’
  In the expression: formURL c p
  In an equation for ‘url’: url = formURL c p
• Relevant bindings include
    p :: proxy s (bound at app/Main.hs:36:18)
    redirectPrompt :: OAuthClient -> proxy s -> IO (OAuthCode s)
      (bound at app/Main.hs:36:1)
```

I have no idea why it gets wrong.. The `p`'s type looks like as same as `formURL` require one.

```
-- https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gogol-0.1.1/docs/Network-Google-Auth.html#v:formURL
formURL :: AllowScopes (s :: [Symbol]) => OAuthClient -> proxy s -> Text
```

Do I misunderstand something?

**Updated**

The version I used was lts-7.19.
After changing from lts-7.19 to lts-8.0, it works.

The ghc version of lts-7.19 is 8.0.1.
The lts-8.0 one is 8.0.2.
Here is some notes of [ghc-8.0.2-released](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/blog/ghc-8.0.2-released).

Comment: I'm unsure, but you could try `(s :: '[Symbol])` (additional single quote) and see what happens.

Comment: @chi just tried it. Ghc asked me to enable `TypeInType`.  Then, it complained 2 errors.  - Expected a type, but ‘'[Symbol]’ has kind ‘[*]’  and - Expected kind ‘[Symbol]’, but ‘s’ has kind ‘'[Symbol]’.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Works with `lts-8.0` and the right dependencies in `.cabal`

```
 build-depends:    base
                 , gogol
                 , gogol-core
                 , process
                 , text
```

You need `{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}` and `import GHC.TypeLits` where `Symbol` is defined.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures    #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds         #-}

module Main where

import Network.Google.Auth
import GHC.TypeLits

import Data.Proxy     (Proxy (..))
import Data.Text      as T
import Data.Text.IO   as T
import System.Exit    (exitFailure)
import System.Info    (os)
import System.Process (rawSystem)

redirectPrompt :: AllowScopes (s :: [Symbol]) => OAuthClient -> proxy s -> IO (OAuthCode s)
redirectPrompt c p = do
 let url = formURL c p
 T.putStrLn $ "Opening URL " `T.append` url
  _ <- case os of
        "darwin" -> rawSystem "open"     [unpack url]
        "linux"  -> rawSystem "xdg-open" [unpack url]
        _        -> T.putStrLn "Unsupported OS" >> exitFailure
T.putStrLn "Please input the authorisation code: "
OAuthCode <$> T.getLine 

main = print "working"
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. In fact, I have `{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}` and `import GHC.TypeLits` in my code and The `.cabal` included all the packages you suggest. But it didn't work. Btw, I use LTS haskell 7.19.

Comment: Well if it helps to know I ran `stack` with a `simple` project and it compiled for me. Hope it helps! btw using `resolver: lts-8.0`.

Comment: It did work after changing from lts-7.19 to lts-8.0. Looks like some of ghc bugs was fixed on new version..